# HighStock with Django: help me render

Tags: python, json, django, highcharts

I was hoping someone could help me with my code.  I've modified the example from [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/) so that it works with Django web framework, but I can't seem to debug it since it doesn't throw any exception, but the chart doesn't render neither. It's very weird. Essentially, I am redirecting the json datasource to read my own local data.

So far, I have the following code in home.html:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="stock_panel" class="stock-body" style="width:100%;height:314px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        var chartDataUrl = "{% url 'chartFishPrice' %}";
        $.getJSON(chartDataUrl,
            function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#stock_panel').highcharts('StockChart', {

            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1,
                inputEnabled: $('#stock_panel').width() > 480
            },

            title : {
                text : 'fish Price'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'chart_data',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});

</script>
```

And this is views.py:

```
def chartFishPrice(request):
    ff = FishCaught.objects.filter(fish_id=1)
    data = {'dates': [], 'values': []}
    for f in ff:
        data['dates'].append(int(f.date_caught.strftime("%s")))
        data['values'].append(int(f.num_caught))
    data2 = {}
    data2['chart_data'] = data
    print data2
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data2), content_type='application/json')
```

and the urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^chartFishPrice/$', 'fish.views.chartFishPrice', name='chartFishPrice'),
```

And I've double checked my data format in json as:

```
{"chart_data": {"dates": [1396310400, 1396396800, 1396483200, 1396569600], "values": [2, 3, 2, 4]}}
```

and for comparison, this is the [sample data from the example](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?):

```
[
/* May 2006 */
[1147651200000,67.79],
[1147737600000,64.98],
[1147824000000,65.26]]
```

This is weird stuff.  I really appreciate any help you can spare.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

But that data doesn't seem to be in the same format at all. You have an object consisting of two arrays, one of "dates" and one of "values". The sample data has an array of arrays, with each sub-array consisting of a single date and a single value.

If you want the same format as the sample, your view should look like this:

```
data = []
for f in ff:
    date = int(f.date_caught.strftime("%s"))
    value = int(f.num_caught)
    date.append([date, value])
```

Comment: Daniel, your solution works great! Thanks. I really appreciate your help. One curious thing that I noticed. In order for the chart to render, I had to multiply date by 1000.  By chance, do you know how to convert the dates to epoch without having to multiply by 1000?

Comment: You need to muliply, because you have UNIX timestamp, but javascript use own timestamps, which are Unix*1000.